# Cannot do a post with jquery with json in body

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

With Chrome REST service I do this: a post to a certain url, I send a json string in the body, I set the content type as application/json and when I execute the post I get the proper answer.
I am trying to do the same post with jquery.
I first try with:

```
var beacon = {"beaconid.minor":2,"beaconid.UUID":"beaconnr","beaconid.major":1}; 

$.ajax({
type: "post",
data: JSON.stringify(beacon),
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "jsonp",
crossDomain: true,
url: "myurl"}).done(function() {
    alert("success");
}).fail(function()
{
    alert("error");
});
```

by I seem to get no answer, I don't get the success alert nor the error alert.

I have then tried with:

```
var jqxhr = $.post( "myurl", {"beaconid.minor":2,"beaconid.UUID":"beaconnr","beaconid.major":1}).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR)
    {

    }).fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
{
    alert(textStatus);
});
```

At least now I get an alert with the textStatus as an error. It is something...but not enough. I could I do a successful post?

Comment: remove `contentType: "application/json",` and try then

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you're setting `dataType: "jsonp"` for a POST request. JSONP doesn't support POST requests, only GET requests.

I suggest changing to `dataType: "json"` to see if the service supports [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). If it doesn't then you'll have to do something like proxy the request through the local server, to get around [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing).

Answer (score 0):

You should not be sending "post" as "type", rather as "method"
And like pointed above, the data type should be json and not jsonp.

```
$.ajax({
method: "post",
data: JSON.stringify(beacon),
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: "json",
url: "myurl"}).done(function(response) {
    alert("success");
    //if in chrome
    //console.log(response);
}).fail(function(error)
{  
    //if using Chrome
    //console.log(error);
    alert(error);
});
```

Comment: OK, I have changed "type" with "method" and "jsonp" with "json" and at least I now get an alert with the error.
How do I understand what kind of error this could be?

Comment: add a parameter to the fail function, and print it in the console (if using Chrome) like this: function(response) { console.log(response); }  (or you can stick with the alert ... (alert(response);)

Comment: I updated my answer to demonstrate what I mean. Look at the new signature of the fail function.

Comment: I get [object Object] as the error...
Anyway, by looking at the console, I can now see a warning saying that the request was blocked due to the cross origin.
I suppose that I have now to change something in the server where the service resides.

Comment: chrome's console will allow you to display the object's content, by expanding the arrow right next to it with a mouse click.

Comment: regarding the warning you got (which, if for cross-origin policy, should not be a warning but an error, from my experience) - follow Mr.Code suggestion above.

Comment: Well Sara, this is as far as I can go - I do not have much experience in cross domain calls - other than starting to research about it recently, for some stuff I was playing with. Can't help further, sorry.

Comment: In Chrome it is indeed an error, while in firefox it is the warning list. I have tried to move this call in the same domain where the service resides and now all seems to work, although I have to find a solution because this page has to be in another domain. @Veverke, it seems that I cannot use "jsonp" withg posts; MrCode said that jsonp supports only get requests. If I try with jsonp I can see in Chrome console that a get request is being made to myurl/Client/……para‌​ms}&_=1422978562744 –

Comment: OK, thank you all for now, at least now with your help the post works!